# How to set the value of a macro using environment variable or command line in verilog?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I want to define a macro during runtime in Verilog using environment variable.

For example, I want to print some text to a file only when the `DEBUG` macro is defined as `1`.

```
`define DEBUG 0
...
if(DEBUG) $fwrite(file,"Debug message");
```

How can I override the definition of `DEBUG` to `1` when running the simulation from command line or using environment variable?

Alternatively, I could keep the macro undefined and use `ifdef`

```
`ifdef(DEBUG) $fwrite(file,"Debug message");
```

In this case I would have to define the macro `DEBUG` when running the simulation. Is this possible?

I am using Modelsim. Thanks.

---

*EDIT*: The accepted answer is sufficient. But I will add this information too for anyone who stumbles upon here.

The value of a parameter can be set/overriden by using `-g<parameter>` or `-G<parameter>` argument to `vsim`. `-g` sets the parameter value only if it hasn't been set already and `-G` set the value even if it's defined. I found this convenient when I control simulation length using parameter. Recompilation isn't necessary.

```
vsim -c work.top -gSIM_END_TIME // Sets value in all scope
vsim -c work.top -g/top/dut/SIM_END_TIME // Sets value only in the defined scope
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override a macro definition with the **vlog** command line option **+define+<*macro_name*>[=<*macro_text*>]**

The better option is to leave the macro undefined and use the  `` `ifdef `` statement to test if you have defined it on the command line.

Note that using a macro requires you to recompile your source code every time you want to change the macro value. Verilog provides `$test$plusargs` and `$value$plusargs` to test command line options at runtime so you do not need to recompile.