# modelsim command to choose a particular test in Verilog testbench

Tags: case, verilog, command-line-arguments, modelsim

I have 4 test patterns and all written inside a case statement in the testbench. How to call each test at a time through command line during simulation?let me know the command line argument for choosing one testbench case at a time during simulation.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

I would use a "define" or $test$plusargs and $value$plusargs for that.

You can define the value of a value on the command line using the +define+ argument.

```
+define+TEST_TO_RUN="4"
```

In your code you can now grab the value using:

```
case(`TEST_TO_RUN)
0 : ...
4 : ...
default: // default test or giving error message and stop 
endcase
```

But you have to re-compile the code. 
You can also set a value in the code but the command line define always overrides that.

Alternative use $test$plusargs and $value$plusargs.

You can also find information about all of that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674839)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the information. I tried with $value$plusargs and is working fine.

Comment: In your comment,Can  I declare TEST_TO_RUN as a reg vector?.

Comment: I have no idea, I used this stuff seldom. Best is to give it a try and see where it ends...