# Are there Vivado and Quartus tool specific defines that RTL can use for preprocessing?

Tags: fpga, vivado, quartus, intel-fpga

I have a project that needs to build in both a Xilinx Vivado toolchain and a Quartus toolchain.  In the design I have some clock crossing domain IP that is specific to the vendors.  Is there a standard define that is present in Vivado or Quartus preprocessing step that I can use to control the ifdef of one IP versus another?

Comment: If you can't find one, you can always use Verilog and define a macro on the command line e.g. `+define+QUARTUS` or `+define+XILINX`. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61027024/)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet on Oldfart's comment, but I'll add that if VHDL, you can use the IF/GENERATE to instantiate the correct IP.  But you say preprocessing - is there something special about that you want?  Perhaps you are thinking along the line of [metacomment pragmas](https://insights.sigasi.com/tech/list-known-vhdl-metacomment-pragmas/)?  There appears to be both a A and X one on the linked page.